# Scroll to a position relative to an anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, anchor

I'd like to scroll to a position that is for ex 20px above an anchor. What is the best solution for this?

**EDIT: I'm going to use [scrollTo with jquery](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html). Couldn't figure out window.location.hash.**

Comment: Do you still need to do this? I missed the edit, see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scroll to the anchor (by setting `window.location.hash`, maybe) then do `window.scrollBy(0, -20)`, for example.